# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - While deploying using hardhat

Tags: solidity, blockchain, contract-deployment, javascript, hardhat-deploy

I am getting the following error while trying to deploy a Mock contract on the hardhat development chain.

I am following:

> Learn Blockchain, Solidity, and Full Stack Web3 Development with JavaScript – 32-Hour Course by Patrick Collins on FreeCodeCamp YT channel

I got this error while I was at `10:48:53` of the above course. I tried almost every thing but nothing helped but I found where the problem was occurring.

**Ques: Where do I think the problem is occurring? (12:26)**

> According to me the problem is at the line where we are trying to deploy the script and we are waiting for the promise to be returned.

Here is the error:

```
rishavsharma@Rishavs-Air buyMeACoffee-dapp % yarn hardhat deploy --tags mocks
yarn run v1.22.18
warning ../../../../../../../../package.json: No license field
$ '/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/node_modules/.bin/hardhat' deploy --tags mocks
Nothing to compile
Development network detected! Deploying mocks...
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: ERROR processing /Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/deploy/00-deploy-mocks.js:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at getFrom (/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/helpers.ts:1713:14)
    at _deploy (/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/helpers.ts:533:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at _deployOne (/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/helpers.ts:1004:16)
    at Object.module.exports [as func] (/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/deploy/00-deploy-mocks.js:12:26)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1219:22)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1052:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:438:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:219:14)
    at Environment.run (/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:131:14)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1222:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1052:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:438:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:219:14)
    at Environment.run (/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:131:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:584:32)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:219:14)
    at Environment.run (/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:131:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/Users/rishavsharma/Documents/working/Web Dev/Blockchain/Freecodecamp/solidity&Block/blockchain-with-js/buyMeACoffee-dapp/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:669:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
rishavsharma@Rishavs-Air buyMeACoffee-dapp %
```

Here is the code snippet in which I am getting the error:

```
const { network } = require("hardhat");
const { developmentChains, DECIMALS, INITIAL_ANSWER } = require("../helper-hardhat-config");

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments;
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
    const chainId = network.config.chainId;


    if (chainId == 31337) {
        console.log("Development network detected! Deploying mocks...");
        const feedMock = await deploy("MockV3Aggregator", {
            contract: "MockV3Aggregator",
            from: deployer,
            log: true,
            args: [DECIMALS, INITIAL_ANSWER],
        });
        log("Price Feed Mock deployed!");
        log("==============================================");
    }
} 
module.exports.tags = ["all", "mocks"];
```

Please help me with this problem

System configuration: MacBook Air M1 2021, Monterey 12.4
yarn: 1.22.18
Hardhat: 2.9.6

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer from the MASTER himself, @PatrickAlphaC.

When we call await getNamedAccounts in the above code, hardhat looks for the length of the named accounts in our hardhat.config.js

We have to make sure that the property given below is in there!

```
namedAccounts: {
    deployer: {
        default: 0, // here this will by default take the first account as deployer
    },
},
```

This solved my problem and I was HAPPY again!

Comment: I had the same error - I misspelt namedAccounts... hard to pick up, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Patrick and Sharma. I struggled last few days with the above issue. Now it's resolved.
By the way, the video course created by Partick is awesome. Thank you again @PatrickAlphaC.